Prove that the function $\bigl(2^{t+c}-1\bigr)\zeta(t)$ is logarithmically concave in $t\in[4,\infty)$
Let
\begin{equation}
c=\log_2\biggl(\frac{1}{16}\frac{60-\pi^2}{15-\pi^2}\biggr)=-0.711\dotsc
\end{equation}
For verifying that the sequence
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(2n+1)(n+1)}\frac{2^{2n+2+c}-1}{2^{2n+c}-1}\biggl|\frac{B_{2n+2}}{B_{2n}}\biggr|
\end{equation}
is decreasing in $n\ge2$, it suffices to show that the function $Y(x)=\bigl(2^{x+c}-1\bigr)\zeta(x)$ is logarithmically concave in $x\in(x_0,\infty)$, where $x_0\in(3,4)$ and $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function.
Could you please give a proof of the logarithmic concavity of the function $Y(x)$ in $x\in[4,\infty)$?
I also believe that the function $Y(x)$ is concave in $x\in(0,1)$ and is convex in $x\in(1,\infty)$.
